# Como aplicar datos guardados en html en un events de fullcalender

Tags: jquery, laravel, html5, fullcalendar, ckeditor

Cordial saludos tengo un problemas, estoy usando FullCalendar donde al momento de recibir un dato(descripcion para ser mas especifico) que en la base de datos se guarda de manera HTML ya que uso CKEDITOR, al momento de pasarlo al evento como que la información llega en formato html y hace que genere error .
Este es el fragmento de código de mi events donde uso htmlspecialchars_decode, asi lo use o no igual se genera error:

```html
events: [
                    @foreach($tareas as $tarea)
                    {
                        id :'2',
                        title : '{!!$tarea->numberdel!!}',
                        start : '{{ $tarea->fech_ini }}',
                        emisor : '{{ $tarea->emisor }}',
                        receptor : '{{ $tarea->receptor }}',
                        acciontarea_id : '{{ $tarea->acctar->name }}',
                        fech_ini : '{{  $tarea->fech_ini  }}',
                        fech_fin : '{{  $tarea->fech_fin  }}',
                        @if($tarea->procesos_id == null)
                        procesos_id : 'sin proceso',           
                        @else
                        procesos_id : '{!! $tarea->proces->name!!}',             
                        @endif
                        @if($tarea->entidad_id == null)
                        entidad_id : 'sin cliente',           
                        @else
                        entidad_id : '{{ $tarea->client->name }}',             
                        @endif
                        @if($tarea->contactos_id == null)
                        contactos_id : 'sin contacto',           
                        @else
                        contactos_id : '{{$tarea->contac->name}}, {{$tarea->contac->lastname}}',             
                        @endif
                        descripcion: '{!! htmlspecialchars_decode( $tarea->descripcion) !!}',
                        textColor: '#ffffff',
                        borderColor : '#007bff',
                    },
                    @endforeach
                ],
```

y es este error que se genera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quítale los saltos de linea... Diria que la `descripcion` tiene que ir en una sola linea. Prueba con `htmlspecialchars_decode( str_replace( "\n", '', $tarea->descripcion ))` por ejemplo

Comment: agradezco su ayuda pero igual me sigue mandando ese error intente con  descripcion: '{{ htmlspecialchars_decode( str_replace( "\n", '', $tarea->descripcion )) }}', pero igual

Comment: ¿Y al hacerlo te quedaba todo en una linea?  ¿o se veia igual?  quizas en lugar de `\n` deberias probar con `\r\n`

Comment: ahora si lo deja todo en una linea agradezco su ayuda

Comment: O sea, que ahora si te funciona, no? Perfecto, voy a ponerlo como respuesta para que conste

Comment: si me funciona lo hice de esta manera -> descripcion: '{!! htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace( "\r\n", '', $tarea->descripcion )) !!}',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El valor de `descripcion` debe ir en una sola línea para que FullCalendar lo pueda interpretar correctamente.

En este caso la solución ha sido modificar esta línea:

```
descripcion: '{!! htmlspecialchars_decode( $tarea->descripcion) !!}',
```

por esta:

```
descripcion: '{!! htmlspecialchars_decode( str_replace( "\r\n", '', $tarea->descripcion )) !!}',
```

forzando la eliminación de los saltos de linea.

**Cambios realizados:**

Básicamente se ha agregado la función [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) sobre el texto que tenia los saltos de linea representados por la variable  `$tarea->descripcion`. A dicha función se le ha pedido que reemplace el string `\r\n` (retorno de carro y nueva línea) por nada, dejándolo vacio y así suprimiéndolos.